# Javax.xml.ws Client for OAuth2.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, webservices-client

I had implementation of client using `javax.xml.ws` for a soap webservice. It work fine with basic authentication. Where I am setting authentication parameters like this

```
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY,"xyz");
bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY,"xyz");
```

But now we have a flow with OAUTH2.0 where I have to send just a Token with Request. I almost banged my head with whole internet but couldn't find the solution using `javax.xml.ws`. There are implementations using `javax.ws.rs` packages but they won't work in my case as I have to use WSDL. Please share a solution so request can be sent using `Authenticaton:Bearer TOKEN_STRING`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can try the same but with `MessageContext`.

```
Map<String,List<String>>headers = new HashMap<>(); 
headers.put("Authorization",Collections.singletonList("Bearer "+token));
bp.getRequestContext().put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);
```